# JPA Many-To-Many Duplicates

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, many-to-many

I have two entities with a many-to-many relationship in my spring boot project:

```
@Entity
public class Competition
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Kind.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Kind> kind;

    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Kind
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

Unfortunately it is possible to create duplicates with the same `name` value. Any ideas how I avoid this?

Comment: @Column(unique=true) on name field? am i misunderstanding your request?

Comment: Are you sure you need a separate `Kind` entity? Perhaps an `@ElementCollection` of strings would suffice? Alternatively, instead of using `@Column(unique=true)`, you could simply use the `name` field as the primary key